# Unit testing an object state change across multiple classes in PHP

Tags: php, unit-testing, pass-by-reference

Scenario: I have a value object that is being passed, by reference, around several objects (in this case event listeners) and whose state is modified in one of the objects. After the event listeners are triggered there is another call that saves the object to the data store with the new state. This has been fixed by making the event listener not work directly with the value object.

Question: How can I write a regression unit test to check that the value object is not modified at the time the save happens?

Example:

```
public function someControllerAction() {
    $value = new \stdClass();
    $value->property = 'awesome';
    $value->type = 'test';

    $obj->method($value);
    $otherObj-> methodChangesStateButShouldNot($value); // If this method is bad it will change the state of value

// Value needs to be the same state as when it was created
    $db->save($value);
}
```

Comment: How is it that you change $value but still want it to be the same?

Comment: @markus sorry the code sample is misleading. `$value` is not supposed to change. It was being used by a method that was changing it & that caused the bug. Basically if I ran a unit test against this code, it should fail.

Comment: So, `methodChangesStateButShouldNot()` ?

Comment: Maybe I don't get the problem but I don't think you should test this here, if the `$otherObj` is not supposed to change the `$value` then a test in that other object::method has to make sure input and output are the same. Testing this here would mean to create a real instance of $otherObj and then maybe a whole lot more of context and that's not the point of unit testing, is it.

Comment: If $otherObj::methodChangesState was a static method you could maybe dare to do it. Just clone the $value and then assert that $value before and after are equal.

Comment: @markus makes sense, want to set it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean `methodChangesStateButShouldNot()` then I don't think you should test this here. If the `$otherObj` is not supposed to change the `$value` then a test in that other `object::method` has to make sure input and output are the same. Testing this here would mean to create a real instance of `$otherObj` instead of a fake and then maybe a whole lot more of context and that's not the point of unit testing, is it.

If `$otherObj::methodChangesState` was a static method you could maybe dare to do it. Just clone the `$value` and then assert that `$value` before and after are equal.